# Visual C++ error C2143 No idea whats missing

Tags: c++, visual-c++

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'

I have no idea whats going on. I am writing like I normally do and this is the first time I have got this error. I am still new and learning so I may miss something obvious but I have no idea what this means, the program looks correct to me. Where am I missing a semi-colon? Its the only error I have too.

```
double LoanA, Interest, monthlyP, balance, totalInterest, monthlyI, LastPay;
int monthCount;

cout << "Enter the loan ammount: $";
cin >> LoanA;
cout << endl << "Enter annual interest rate in percentage: ";
cin >> Interest;
cout << endl << "Enter monthly payment: $";
cin >> monthlyP;
cout << endl;

monthCount = 1;
balance = LoanA;
totalInterest = 0;
monthlyI = 0;

Interest = Interest/100;

while (balance > 0)
    {

        monthlyI = (balance*Interest)12;
        balance = balance + monthlyI;
        balance = balance - monthlyP;
        totalInterest = totalInterest + monthlyI;
        monthCount++;
        cout << "month: " << monthCount << " Interest paid: " << monthlyI << " Remaining debt: " << balance << endl;

    }

LastPay = (balance+monthlyP)+monthlyI;

cout << "Total number of payments = " << monthCount << endl;
cout << "Total amount of interest paid = " << totalInterest << endl;
cout << "The last payment = " << LastPay << endl;
```

Comment: `monthlyI = (balance*Interest)12;` Most probably there.

Comment: The compiler should tell you which line the error is at. Did you look at that line? Did it contain a bogus expression like `(balance*Interest)12`?

Comment: It says "syntax error : missing ';'...". So, there is something wrong with *syntax*. As others said  *(balance*Interest)12* - is wrong (syntactically).

Answer (score 2):

This line is invalid syntax

```
monthlyI = (balance*Interest)12;
//                          ^^^
```

you might meant:

```
monthlyI = (balance*Interest) / 12;
//                           ^^^^
```

Comment: Oh of course! I simply overlooked the syntax! I was looking for semi-colons for some reason. Thank you much!